# PHP Can't login with cUrl

Tags: php, forms, curl, authentication

I have this form on a page:

```
<form name="logForm" method="post" action="j_security_check" onsubmit="return validateLogin(this);" _lpchecked="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="j_username">
    <input type="hidden" name="catId" value="10000">
    <input type="hidden" name="redURL" value="/loggedIn.do">    
        <table border="0" bordercolor="pink" id="login-table">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><input id="userId" type="text" name="username" class="login-fields phfield" value="username"></td>
                <td><input id="pwd" type="password" name="j_password" class="login-fields phfield" value="password"></td>
                <td rowspan="2" style="width: 105px;">
                    <input type="submit" value="" class="login_btn" id="login-submit">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </form>
```

Here, what's the difference between the hidden **j_username** and the input name **username** ? Do I need to post the "username", isn't it?

So, about this form I set vars and try login:

```
$cookiefile = tempnam ("/tmp", "mycookiefile.txt");
$login = 'https://example.com/folder/j_security_check';
$cookiedata = array(
"username" => "myusername",
"j_password" => "mypassword"
);

// try to login
$ch = curl_init ($login);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('verbose.txt', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cookiedata);
$out = curl_exec ($ch);
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

            if ($headers == 404 || curl_errno($ch) != 0)
            {
                    echo "Error \n";
            }
echo $out;
```

I can't login, it redirects at the login failure page.

Please, where is it wrong? Thanks

Verbose:

```
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to example.come (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.example.com
*   start date: Aug 10 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*   expire date: Aug 10 23:59:59 2017 GMT
*   common name: *.example.com
*   issuer: CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US
> POST /folder/j_security_check HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 370
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------e6df4811bbdc

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Wed, 03 May 2017 14:38:21 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
< Location: https://example.com/folder/loginFailure.do
< Content-Length: 0
* Added cookie logged-user="""" for domain example.com, path /, expire 786297600
< Set-Cookie: logged-user=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Dec-94 16:00:00 GMT; Path=/; Domain=example.com
* Added cookie JSESSIONID="0000CKKhQSS79AIRXhTP-REhHSI:18hmtvfl9" for domain example.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000CKKhQSS79AIRXhTP-REhHSI:18hmtvfl9; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Language: en-US
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

these are the copied CURLs by Chrome when login by browser...

```
//homepage

curl "https://example.com/folder/viewHome.do" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br" -H "Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Referer: https://example.com/" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000IqYX1pKkYILlDsHqo2TfZLO:18hmtvhe1; LtpaToken2=... ...; LtpaToken=... ...; logged-user=myuser" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed

//j_security_check
curl "https://example.com/folder/j_security_check" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000IqYX1pKkYILlDsHqo2TfZLO:18hmtvhe1; LtpaToken2=tokenLongString... ...; LtpaToken=tokenLongString... ..." -H "Origin: https://example.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Referer: https://example.com/folder/viewHome.do" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data "j_username=myuser^&catalogId=10000^&redirectURL=^%^2FloggedIn.do^&username=myuser^&j_password=mypassword" --compressed
```

Comment: You've output verbose to a file, but not included any of the output. add the contents of verbose.txt to your question.

Comment: @Luke added the verbose...thank you

Comment: the `HTTP error before end of send, stop sending` line suggests that the response was terminated by the target server

Comment: obviously I can login with the same username and password by browser...

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the code for the Javascript method, validateLogin().

**j_username** is hidden and inaccessible to the user. The visible input, ...`name="username"`..., will contain the username provided by the user. Pass this to your PHP code for a successful login.

**EDIT: New information provided in comments**
You are not using the $_POST data. You are trying to pass data in your curl code that hasn't been set (that we can see). Try this substitution:

```
$cookiedata = array(
   "username" => $_POST['j_username'],
   "j_username" => $_POST['j_username'],
   "j_password" => $_POST['j_password']
);
```

**Edit:** added both username fields, because of your chrome curl update looks to be using both

Comment: Indeed I pass that...but failure

Comment: Still need your javascript code. That passes your data to PHP, right?

Comment: what do you mean, exactly? That's not my server...what javascript code?

Comment: looks like _j_username_ value is set from the _username_ input via javascript. I can't help though, because all the code you provided isn't giving the whole picture. The $_post data isn't used in the code, and the login script is looking for set cookies, which is not set in any of the code you provided.

Comment: "The $_post data isn't used in the code..." ? and how to set cookies? is $cookiefile not enough? I don't understand, sorry...

Comment: I updated my answer after this new information. Please pick my answer as correct if it works.

Comment: added the copied CURLs by Chrome when login by browser...if they help

Comment: I can't understand your $_POST... how it sets the correct vars this way? username and password must be set before sending them...

Comment: The issue I'm seeing is that the cookies have never been set. This uses the data that the form provides. Just try the edit and report back

Comment: What does your form post to? This curl script?

Comment: yes, need to understand why this script doesn't work...all is done by the script, connection, post etc...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

better if you check the "Request header" by browser, in order to emulate the exact request.

In this case the **Content-Type** must be **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

so, `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cookiedata);` is not good.

You need to:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($cookiedata));
```